# How to Fix Coinbase Pro API Request Headers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coinbase-api

I am trying to code to execute orders using Coinbase Pro API according to the [Documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/) provided. However, I got an error like this.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com/orders' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field cb-access-key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

And this is the code that I wrote.

```
            var vm = this;

            var coinbasePro = {
                passphrase: 'xxxxxxxxx',
                key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                secret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==',
                apiURI: 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
            };

            var dataRequest = {
                url: '/orders',
                method: 'POST',
                timestamp: Date.now() / 1000,
            };

            var dataBody = JSON.stringify({
                price: '1.0',
                size: '1.0',
                side: 'buy',
                product_id: 'BTC-USD'
            });

            var what = vm.dataRequest.timestamp + vm.dataRequest.method + vm.dataRequest.url + dataBody;
            var key = Buffer.from(vm.coinbasePro.secret, 'base64');
            var hmac = cryptoJs.createHmac('sha256', key);
            var sign = hmac.update(what).digest('base64');

            vm.$http({
                url: vm.coinbasePro.apiURI+vm.dataRequest.url,
                method: vm.dataRequest.method,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'CB-ACCESS-KEY': vm.coinbasePro.key,
                    'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': sign,
                    'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': vm.coinbasePro.passphrase,
                    'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': vm.dataRequest.timestamp,
                },
            }).then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            }).catch((err) => {

            });
```

I have tried different ways to get things going and applied some of the references I have come across. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Because that API doesn't support CORS, it's likely that it's not intended to be accessed directly from a page. Instead, access it from your server. Your server can act as a kind of proxy for that API. (You won't be able to make it work from just the browser.)

Answer (score 1):

Their API does support CORS, however it is misconfigured and does not permit the security headers that they require you to use!  You can work around this by running an express proxy with middleware to re-write the headers:

```
import express from 'express'
import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware'

const app = express()

app.use(express.static('client'))

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com',
  changeOrigin: true,
  onProxyRes: res => {
    res.headers = {
      ...res.headers,
      'access-control-allow-headers':
        'Content-Type, cb-access-key, cb-access-sign, cb-access-timestamp, cb-access-passphrase',
    }
  },
})

app.use('/', apiProxy)

app.listen(3001)
```