# How to pull wallet information/balance from Coinbase API

Tags: excel, coinbase-api

I'm trying to get a program working that will simply get wallet data and crypto prices from the coinbase API, I'm not looking to make buy/sell/trade requests with it.

I've been going through the API and the connection tutorial however I can't for the life of me work out how to pull the data from my wallet or crypto prices in to an excel document.

I'd really appreciate any help with this or if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great

I've tried too many combinations of things to list them all here, but mainly various variations of the following:

https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts + Client_ID + Client_Secret = Invalid Token Error
https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts + API_Key + API_Secret = Auhtentication Error - Invalid API Key (Is my valid key)

I have been able to get results using the Coinbase_Python module however that isn't helpful in this scenario when I want the data to auto-populate an excel sheet

**Update:** I was able to fix the issue by redoing the entire process and better labling my values.

My issue now is that I am getting an "Invalid Scope", when it should have access to everything

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and where you have run into problems,

Comment: I've updated the post with a couple things I've tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Fix Coinbase Pro API Request Headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65377808/how-to-fix-coinbase-pro-api-request-headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re authorising the whole code/token thing with a modified authorisation URL I made I was able to access my data properly

Answer (score 0):

It seems you figured it out; you do need the three pieces of authentication (which is somewhat unusual) in addition to the API endpoint for successful access. This is not the norm, especially with cryptocurrency APIs.